# Does FFMPEG utilize CUDA or any other hardware acceleration yet?

Tags: cuda, ffmpeg, gpu, hardware-acceleration, libavcodec

Simple question, but I am having trouble finding the answer.

We are deciding on a transcoding engine (preferrably open source) and it looks to me that FFMPEG does not utilize hardware acceleration, but I am not sure.

I believe ffmpeg uses libavcodec, the same library used in countless other products, such as Handbrake. I can't believe they don't support hardware acceleration, therefore, my question.

Answer (score 1):

libavcodec has API which allows clients to implement hardware decoding. I don't think Handbrake supports it.

This does *not* use CUDA kernels or any other kind of SIMD language, all of which are useless for the task. It uses dedicated decoder hardware packaged with the GPU (or newer CPU). CUDA happens to provide an API to access this, which is what "CUDA support" means.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ffmpeg does not utilize CUDA, if you are curious about something that does - [CoreAVC Video Decoder](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc) has such an option in their H.264 decoder.

Answer (score 0):

I use Loiloscope. It has featured CUDA accelerated transcodes since it's first release.

Answer (score 0):

If you call avcodec_find_decoder() to get decoder, FFmpeg will not utilize hardware acceleration to decode. Instead, calling avcodec_find_decoder_by_name() with specific hardware decoder will gain the GPU utilization. For example:

```
AVCodec *avcodec_h264dec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_cuvid");
```